# how to send a request to one of the IIS handlers programatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

i have a legacy 3rd party application which submits data to our internal sales system. It exposes ASP page with a form to the internet as follows:

```
<form id="ServiceRequest" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="AddToServiceRequest.csp">
```

where `AddToServiceRequest.csp` is a proprietary IIS handler:

[image]

Right now we embed this form into our ASP.Net 4 website using iframe - and that is really inconvenient. What I want to do is to replace this form with a native form, do all validation etc - and then call `AddToServiceRequest.csp` handler from **code-behind logic**. What's the right way to do it? I can think only about something like this:

```
var r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/AddToServiceRequest.csp");
r.Method = "POST";
r.KeepAlive = false;
// fill in form data
var res = r.GetResponse();
res.Close();
```

but it just does not look "right" to me. Are there any other ways?

Comment: What would you consider "right"? Also please clarify if "/AddToServiceRequest.csp" is part of the same web application or separate (clearly you have no other options if this page is on other site than yours).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "AddToServiceRequest.csp" is not a page or part of any webapplication - it's a DLL which handles a request. Regarding "what is right" - well, i don't know - that's why i'm asking. May be there a more appropriate way to send requests to the handler in the IIS.

Comment: My question was - does the request to `http://localhost/AddToServiceRequest.csp` go to the same AppDomain (IIS Site) as you application or not. Because only way to be able to call handler more directly if it runs as part of your site (same app pool / same site).

Comment: hmm... I think nothing prevents me from registering this very same DLL as a IIS HttpHandler for my site. And then it will be part of my site - correct?

Comment: There is pretty much no chance it will work if registered for another site that it is designed to (like missing DB connections/settings) - so since it is no part of *your* site you'll need to make web request (there are many ways, but all we more or less the same as code you've posted). You may also need to allow "loopback connections" (I think in some configurations calls from localhost to localhost sites are disabled).

Comment: Converted most of comments into an answer so question no longer looks like open.

Answer (score 0):

If handler serving request is for some other site (from IIS point of view) than code for it will run in separate process or separate AppDomain and you will have no reasonable way to call it directly.

If handler is registered for the same site as yours you may be able to invoke it directly - i.e. if it is APS.Net class that handles request than it just an interface with couple methods - you may be able to instantiate and execute it directly. Note that many handlers depend on `HttpContext.Current` and you may not be able to set request reasonably for such calls.

It is also unlikely to register same handler to your site as most handlers/controllers/forms are designed to work for particularly configured site (i.e. Web.Config will have DB connection info).

So making direct web request is most straightforward solution. I would not try any other way as most web code will not handle unusual ways of invocation correctly.

You may consider `HttpClient` instead of `WebRequest` to get easier `async` supoprt (assuming .Net 4.5+), but any way of setting up request is ok.

Note that if site uses Windows Authentication you may not be able to pass user information via Web request .